# Windows .NET is unable to overrite a file but Robocopy can

Tags: .net, windows, stream, filestream, robocopy

I am trying to overwrite a file (say `//server/dir/file.dat`) using a .NET function to open it:

```
IO.FileStream('//server/dir/file.dat', IO.FileMore.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write, IO.FileShare.None, 1024, False)
```

But I get a permission error:

> the process cannot access the file `\\server\dir\file.dat` because it being
>   used by another process

However, when I do the same type of operation in Robocopy:

```
ROBOCOPY \\ServerFrom\dir1 \\Server\dir file.dat
```

It works! So, how come Robocopy and do the transfer but not the .NET algorithm? What trickery of permissions is going on? I suppose I could replace my .NET functions with just Robocopy, but I would much rather keep my program self contained.

Note: I am unable to open the file for reading or writing, so I don't even get to the point of copying. The error happens in the `IO.FileStream` constructor.

Note2: In regular Windows Explorer, I am also unable to delete the file. So I know it much be some kind of windows thing. However because Robocopy can access the file, I know there is a way around this.

Comment: Try `IO.FileShare.Delete|IO.FileShare.ReadWrite` instead of `IO.FileShare.None`.  The other trick robocopy can do is to use backup privilege to override file permissions, but that shouldn't be relevant to the specific error message you're getting.

Comment: Actually it would be interesting to know how to use .NET to get file access in backup mode. For the record, I was not intentionally running Robocopy in that mode.

Comment: I don't *think* robocopy uses backup privileges unless you explicitly ask it to with the `/b` flag.  But I'm not absolutely certain.  As for .NET, I don't know the answer to that or even whether it's possible, but if you want to post a question about it I'll upvote. :-)  (Better search the site first, it might have already been answered.)